# runtime for search of linked-list datastructure using “jumpset” algorithm

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I have this assignment where i need to use an algorithm called jumpset to implement search in a sorted linked list L.

The jumpset algorithm assigns 1 or more "jump" pointers to each object in L.

Initially x.jump is set to x.next for each object x in L

Then a loop is entered which continues so long L.head.jump!=NIL.

For each iteration i of this loop an inner loop is initiated which traverses the objects in L, skipping 2i objects per iteration.

So for example, for a list of length 10 we get

1st iteration:

L[1].jump.= L[3]

L[3].jump=L[5]

L[5].jump=L[7]

L[7].jump=L[9]

L[9].jump=NIL

2nd iteration

L[1].jump=L[5]

L[5].jump=L[9]

3rd iteration

L[1].jump=L[9]

4th iteration

L[1].jump=NIL

I believe i understand how to search for an object x using the pointers generated by the above algorithm. If we store the pointers assigned to x in x.p, you just start with L.head.p and follow its trail of pointers until you reach an object y equal to or larger than x. if x=y you return TRUE, else you repeat the same process L[y].

Eventually, if x is not in L you will reach a NIL object from which there are no pointers and so you return FALSE.

My problem is i cannot figure out the runtime of this method.

Obviously its O(n), but the naive solution for insertion into a linked list has O(n) time too, so it seems reasonable to assume this method would lower the boundary. Why else should we bother with this method?

I hope someone can help me.

if needed here is the original specification of the algorithM for jumpset:

https://i.redd.it/7wzg2lxii6c01.png

Comment: Any connection with "skip list" data structure  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) ?

Comment: there does seem to be a connection. if we were to output all notes visited by jumpset in iteration i as layer i in a multilayered structure we would get what they call a perfect skip list. but in my problem the idea is to create a separate table for each object in the original list containing all the jump pointers this object has been given. we should then use this structure to optimize insertion